# Load images using vue + webpack

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying this:

```
<img src="./src/assets/logo.png"></img>
```

Or This

```
background-image: url("./src/assets/logo.png");
```

I'have made the npm install url-loader@1.1.1
npm install file-loader --save-dev.

But I recive this message

```
* ./src/assets/logo.png in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-219927dc","hasScoped":true,"transformToRequire":{"video":["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/view/login/Login.vue
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your vue components and css files are located inside the **src** directory correct? In that case you need to change your url to

```
<img src="../assets/logo.png"></img>
```

or

```
background-image: url("../assets/logo.png");
```

Comment: I recive that:

Failed to compile.

./src/view/login/Login.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=219927dc&lang=css&scoped=true& (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/view/login/Login.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=219927dc&lang=css&scoped=true&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/img/aqtech/logo_aqtech_branco_com_sombra.png' in 'local path*'

Comment: are you still using url-loader? That is not necessary, did you also update the url on your img tag?